# CGContextAddPath StoryBoard issue

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Firstly i have experienced AUTO LAYOUT issues in StoryBorad.When i have resolved these issues now two new errors are occurring. Please let me know if any one have any idea about these errors.

Errors are giving below:

: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

: clip: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.